# How to crawl server side dynamically generated pages

Tags: java, web-crawler

I need to crawl a few websites. The problem is that - Am I wrong? - that most of the crawlers just go over the links in the website but do not crawl dynamic links. In other words, pages that are generated from databases (i.e. the URL contains a query with '?') will not be crawled.

Do you know a crawler that can perform this job? I've searched over here and found only answers regarding crawling javascript-generated content, and that's not what I want.

BTW I use Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to crawl over dynamically generated URL's. According to google, they are able to scan dynamic URLs, so the technology is certainly there: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

You can easily verify this, by doing a wget of a dynamic url, i.e. http://mysite.com/?page=2

However the complexity arises when your crawler has to deal with sessionID's and cookies, and pages that reveal content on mouseover or other dynamic features. I can imagine a site like gmail or facebook harder to crawl then say for example wikipedia.

In essence, if you can download the page to your harddrive by doing a wget, it is also possible to use Java to save the page into a text file, and then parse the string content within it.

Have a look at crawler4j, as a good starting point. If it is too complicated, write your own java code to do it.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

This page can then be parsed (I tend to find wget/sed/awk/perl faster for this) using java's string manipulation methods.

Comment: This code is working.. but its not crawling.. It retrieved only javascript/css file.. we asking crawl the Dynamic webpages contents..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what it means to be dynamically generated. Any content generated on the server side is not dynamic at the point that a crawler sees it. URLs with a `?` in them are not special. It's possible the crawler software that you are using is ignoring links to URLs containing a question mark, but that's probably just to avoid crawling pages infinitely. The risk is that any dynamically generated content may not have a finite number of pages. Of course, many web development frameworks generate content server side without using query parameters at all. This content will be dynamic and yet transparent to any crawler. Again, you'll still have the issue of potentially crawling an infinite set of dynamically generated pages, but there's no easy way to detect that you are crawling an infinite site. Determining whether or not you should keep crawling links from a set of pages on a dynamically generated site is effectively equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Now you specifically said you *weren't interested* in crawling Javascript, but Javascript is really the only way for there to be dynamic content as far as the *client* is concerned.